# The server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, http-status-code-404

I am trying to instantiate a class in one JavaScript file in another HTML file but I keep on getting this error.

Here is the code for the JavaScript file:

```
class Puzzle {
  constructor(fenStart, pgnEnd) {
    this.fenStart = fenStart;
    this.pgnEnd = pgnEnd;
  }
}
```

And here is the code for the HTML. It should be noted that I am also using chessboard.js and chess.js and that everything is saved in the same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chess</title>
    <base href="http://chessboardjs.com/" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chessboard.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="js/chess.js"></script>
  <div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
  <p>PGN: <span id="pgn"></span></p>
  <script src="js/json3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/chessboard.js"></script>
  <script src="class.js"></script>

    <script>
      var pgnEl = $('#pgn');

      const x = new Puzzle("test", "test");

      pgnEl.html(x.fenStart);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Should the path be `js/class.js`?

Comment: You are missing the starting <body> tag

Comment: Changed to 'js/class.js' and added the starting body tag however no the errors still persist

Answer (score 0):

This could be a result from improper file locations, like @sideroxylon said, `js/class.js` instead of `class.js`.

"The HTML `<base>` tag is used to specify a base URI, or URL, for relative links." https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_base_tag.htm This could be another reason your file is inaccessible.

It could also be from certain URL's being blocked. Try opening Developer Console (CTRL-SHIFT-I or F12) and looking for any errors on your page.

If you're loading over HTTPS any content from an HTTP source may be blocked. Here is your exact code (using online versions of each library) but with the class.js file loaded in as a regular script tag and including the starting `<body>` tag.
https://jsfiddle.net/ckazwozg/ As you *should* see, it is working quite well.

**Edit:** For convenience, here is the raw source code from the JSFiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chess</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/master/src/chessboard.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.10.2/chess.js"></script>
  <div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
  <p>PGN: <span id="pgn"></span></p>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/master/src/chessboard.js"></script>
  <script>
  // class.js
  class Puzzle {
    constructor(fenStart, pgnEnd) {
        this.fenStart = fenStart;
        this.pgnEnd = pgnEnd;
    }
    }
  </script>

    <script>
      var pgnEl = $('#pgn');

      const x = new Puzzle("test", "test");

      pgnEl.html(x.fenStart);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried changing it from 'class.js' to 'js/class.js' however the error persisted. The errors in developer console are 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' and 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Puzzle is not defined'.

Comment: That means that "class.js" cannot be found. The location for the resource is incorrect or the resource is nonexistant. Verify where "class.js" is located relative to your index.html file first, and then put in the correct information about its location.

Comment: I created a new folder with the `chessboard.js` and the `chess.js` files copied in it. I then created a new `class.js` file in it and a `index.html` file it in with the code shown above. However the previously mentioned errors persist. Here is a screenshot of the folder: [link](http://prntscr.com/i3d9u2)

Comment: index.html should be able to acquire "class.js" with the src of the file simply being "class.js"

Comment: I changed it back to `class.js` however these two [errors](http://prntscr.com/i3de4n) still appear

Comment: I Don't know. Might be your host. You aren't loading the file in with a "/" after the extension of the file right? If all comes down to worse, just copy the code from the example above and delete class.js.

Comment: I seem to have found what the problem is using firefox's developer console as you can see in this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/i3dfmu) it is trying to load `class.js` as `http://chessboardjs.com/class.js`, using `http://chessboardjs.com` as the base link. Is there a way to solve this issue with out creating the Puzzle class in the `index.html` file?

Comment: Probably getting rid of the <base> tag in <head>.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error however what I did was ensure all my files are been saved to the root folder in your case I think that's js(since all your extension points to that location) in my case I've  used only the file name after giving it javascript extension (.js) e.g...